# how to replace a part of a string with with a new string containing the part in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have strings like this

```
var str1 = "EmployeeName1";
```

`str1` can  be `"EmployeeName2"` or `"EmployeeName3"` or `"EmployeeName4"`.

I want to search `str1` for a single digit (1,2,3,4) and replace the single digit with a string containing the digit so that

```
"EmployeeName1" -> "EmployeePosition1"

"EmployeeName2" -> "EmployeePosition2"

"EmployeeName3" -> "EmployeePosition3"
```

How to access the found digit 1, 2, 3 and use in regular expression?
something like

```
str1.replace([0-9]/ig, "Position?????")
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)? It's right there.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand what you wanna do but to use regular expression you need to do something like this

r=RegExp('[0-9]');

str1.replace(r,'Position');

Comment: the solution you suggested won't work. The output would be "EmployeeName1" -> "EmployeeNamePosition"   "ProductName2"-> "ProductNamePosition". Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure ? Try this directly online https://jsfiddle.net/osd4gwm4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var names=["EmployeeName1","EmployeeName2","EmployeeName3"]
var positions=["EmployeePosition1", "EmployeePosition2", "EmployeePosition3"]

function get(name){

    var num=parseInt(name.replace( /^\D+/g, ''))
    var pos=positions.map(function(el){return parseInt(el.replace( /^\D+/g, ''))})

    return positions[pos.indexOf(num)]
}

console.log( get(names[0]) )
```